# How do I resolve not fully installed package (python3-setuptools)?

Tags: python, apt-get, dpkg

I was trying to install python3-setuptools, and when i run

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3-setuptools (0.6.34-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 25, in <module>
    from debpython.pydist import PUBLIC_DIR_RE
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/pydist.py", line 28, in <module>
    from debpython.tools import memoize
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/tools.py", line 25, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: /usr/bin/datetime.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
dpkg: error processing python3-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-setuptools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get remove python3-setuptools`, `dpkg --remove python3-setuptools`, but none of them worked.

Comment: Did you try `dpkg --purge`?

Comment: Btw, it would be better to ask this question on http://askubuntu.com or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jrennie `dpkg --purge` gave the same error
Thans will post it in askubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove #your-package-name#
```

and then

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Finally, you can remove all the packages that not fully installed or removed.